# How to get categories from an order at checkout in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I am want to get the category of the items in the cart at the checkout in WooCommerce. I want to extract it and then place it in a field in my custom checkout.

I'm using [**WooCommerce MultiStep Checkout Wizard**](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-multistep-checkout-wizard/8125187) premium plugin and a [**specific hook**](http://woocommerce-multistep-checkout.mubashir09.com/documentation/):

```
add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before_order_info', 'destinationStep');
```

I'm a little lost and can't find much [**documentation**](http://woocommerce-multistep-checkout.mubashir09.com/documentation/) for what I need to use to get it.

I'm trying to just get items to appear but I just get an empty array.

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items(); 
var_dump($items);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could try first with your approach **"`new WC_Order( $order_id );`"**, this way:

```
function destinationStep( $order_id )

    global $woocommerce; 

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    // echo var_dump($items);

    //----
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        // echo var_dump($terms);

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            // Categories by slug
            $product_cat_slug= $term->slug;
        }
    }

add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before_order_info', 'destinationStep', 10, 1);
```

If it still doesn't work try with **"`new WC_Order($post->ID)`"** approach:

```
function destinationStep()

    global $woocommerce, $post; 

    $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    // echo var_dump($items);

    //----
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
        // echo var_dump($terms);

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            // Categories by slug
            $product_cat_slug= $term->slug;
        }
    }

add_action('woocommerce_multistep_checkout_before_order_info', 'destinationStep');
```

---

**Update** - After some thought:

> You **can't get the order Id** for `'post_type' => 'shop_order', because it doesn't exist yet. This order ID is generated when customer submit the order, but not before on checkout page.
>   So in this case, it's normal to get an empty array.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, neither are working for me. I'm only using the first bit of the code at the start and trying to get the var dump. Both var dumps are empty arrays. Any advice? I'll buy you some tequila if we can get this going :)

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well. Just the first part without the loop. Just an empty array.

Comment: Just upvoted for the assistance this is what I've read elsewhere, it's not just working for me.

Comment: No, both just give empty arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114488/discussion-between-josip-godly-zirdum-and-loictheaztec).